# Image / product slider not working only on Magento Frontend Homepage

Tags: magento-1.9, home, slider

I have developed new home page. As one of the internal pages.But when I tried to move it into the initial location (home url).I found that top banner is not working and product slider as well. All internal pages of my website show the image slider, and the product slider without any problems, but the homepage is not displaying it. Can somebody help me to find what is wrong.

Console shows js error: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hammer is not a function.

Home page: http://www.byrneandohanlon.com/emerald/

Internal page (home page preview) fully working: http://www.byrneandohanlon.com/emerald/new_home

Answer (score 1):

I found what was wrong, some strange peace of code in the js file, that was causing jquery not to load properly. 
Once I have removed the .hammer() which was located just before the function name. Everything went back to normal.

Comment: Could you mark this answer as being the solution to the question? Thanks

Comment: Though you are saying your problem is solved still i think its must not the issue of that function that you removed. I think on home page jquery is conflicting with other jquery.